# What is the size of clustered index compared to a table size

Tags: indexing, db2

I have recently attended an Interview and an Interviewer asked me a question.

I have a table with 3 columns: ID, First_Name, Last_Name and the table size is 100 GB. I have created a clustered index on ID column then tell me what will be the size of clustered index? > 100 GB, < 100 GB, or = 100GB?

If > 100 GB or < 100 GB then how much approximately it will be greater than or less than 100GB?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: The question in that form is nonsense. How is table size measured, is compression used, what are the data types and typical column length, what is the PCTFREE setting, ...?

Comment: The answer depends on the actual Db2 version/platform.

Comment: He didn't mention all these details PCTFREE setting, column length, etc. All he provided was the above details, ID column is number, First_Name column is varchar and same for Last_Name. All he wanted to know was whether Clustered Index size will be more, less or greater than the table_size?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0004929.html

> For each uncompressed index, the space needed can be estimated as:
>       (average index key size + index key overhead) × number of rows × 2

So it depends on how wide the First_Name and Last_Name columns are in proportion to ID. If the table and/or index is compressed, then it is a trickier calc.

My guess is that, assuming neither are compressed, the index would be somewhat, but not hugely smaller than the table.

I would also be tempted to ask the interviewer what they are doing with 100GB worth of people's names..  that is almost enough space to hold the name of every single person on the planet!  Are you sure that is a company you want to work for ;-)

Comment: In Db2 for LUW "clustered index" means something completely different than in Db2 for z/OS or System i, so knowing the database platform is key to even starting the discussion.